# Add curves to bar graph

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

I've trying to do graph like this [image: what I need]

But only thing I've got is

[image: what I got]

I was trying bezier path, but it wont work like i need, just have no idea what to do

that code for bezier

```
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path setLineWidth:3.0];
[path setLineCapStyle:kCGLineCapRound];
[path setLineJoinStyle:kCGLineJoinRound];

NSValue *value = [newPoints objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p1 = [value CGPointValue];
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0, viewHeight/2)];

for (int k=1; k<[newPoints count];k++) {

    NSValue *value = [newPoints objectAtIndex:k];
    CGPoint p2 = [value CGPointValue];

    CGPoint centerPoint = CGPointMake((p1.x+p2.x)/2, (p1.y+p2.y)/2);

    if (p1.y<p2.y) {
        centerPoint = CGPointMake(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y+(fabs(p2.y-centerPoint.y)));
    }else if(p1.y>p2.y){
        centerPoint = CGPointMake(centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y-(fabs(p2.y-centerPoint.y)));
    }

    [path addQuadCurveToPoint:p2 controlPoint:centerPoint];
    p1 = p2;
}

[path stroke];
```

it was close to result, but not the same
and I used only top points of graph, not all

current result with this code

[image]

or how could I using mask take only things that between bezier line and green line at center? Then i make bars height just all of view and line will cut them like I need

Comment: how do you mean you tried bezier but it did not work? how did you calculate the curve's points and control points?

Comment: edit my post with answer

Answer (score 1):

you can try by UIBezierPath , just first use

```
[urPath moveToPoint:firstPOint];
loop 
 [urPath addLineToPoint:topOfEveryBar];
```

Comment: then it will be totally wrong, I will get  just straight line, already try it

Comment: @pluck I'm bit busy but I am giving a link to Ray Wenderlich post to let u know that a straight lne is not what it looks like [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/90693/modern-core-graphics-with-swift-part-2)  . In this post a line chart is made

Comment: I mean my points too close to each other, so it will look like many waves

Comment: @pluck can u post ur code at github or somewhere . I'ld like to give it a shot

Comment: or how could I using mask take only things that between bezier line and green line at center? Then i make bars height just all of view and line will cut them like I need

Comment: in your drawBar:context: method you can get populate your indexes array CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(rect)/2, CGRectGetMaxY(rect)/2) that will give you mid point of top bar line . hope so :)

Comment: sorry, not sure I understand you right, you mean take mid points and stroke line through? but it will show wrong result, or you mean something else?